# Match two numpy arrays to find the same elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare, match

I have a task kind of like SQL search. I have a "table" which contains the following 1D arrays (about 1 million elements) identified by `ID1`:

```
ID1, z, e, PA, n
```

Another "table" which contains the following 1D arrays (about 1.5 million elements) identified by `ID2`:

```
ID2, RA, DEC
```

I want to match `ID1` and `ID2` to find the common ones to form another "table" which contains `ID, z, e, PA, n, RA, DEC`. Most elements in `ID1` can be found in `ID2` but not all, otherwise I can use `numpy.in1d(ID1,ID2)` to accomplish it. Anyone has fast way to accomplish this task?

For example:

```
ID1, z, e, PA, n
101, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8
104, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 3.1
105, 1.4, 2.0, 3.3, 2.8

ID2, RA, DEC
101, 4.5, 10.5
107, 90.1, 55.5
102, 30.5, 3.3
103, 60.1, 40.6
104, 10.8, 5.6
```

The output should be

```
ID, z, e, PA, n, RA, DEC
101, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 4.5, 10.5
104, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 3.1, 10.8, 5.6
```

Comment: Add a runnable sample and expected o/p?

Comment: pandas is the right place to look when it comes to merging/joining datasets: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with swapped places for the first columns of the two arrays/tables, such that we would have two masks to index into the arrays for selection. Then, simply stack the results -

```
mask1 = np.in1d(a[:,0], b[:,0])
mask2 = np.in1d(b[:,0], a[:,0])
out = np.column_stack(( a[mask1], b[mask2,1:] ))
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[ 101. ,    1. ,    1.2,    1.5,    1.8],
       [ 104. ,    1.5,    1.8,    2.2,    3.1],
       [ 105. ,    1.4,    2. ,    3.3,    2.8]])

In [45]: b
Out[45]: 
array([[ 101. ,    4.5,   10.5],
       [ 102. ,   30.5,    3.3],
       [ 103. ,   60.1,   40.6],
       [ 104. ,   10.8,    5.6],
       [ 107. ,   90.1,   55.5]])

In [46]: mask1 = np.in1d(a[:,0], b[:,0])

In [47]: mask2 = np.in1d(b[:,0], a[:,0])

In [48]: np.column_stack(( a[mask1], b[mask2,1:] ))
Out[48]: 
array([[ 101. ,    1. ,    1.2,    1.5,    1.8,    4.5,   10.5],
       [ 104. ,    1.5,    1.8,    2.2,    3.1,   10.8,    5.6]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually what I want to match is the `ID`'s. I tried it like this `mask1 = np.in1d(ID1, ID2)` and `mask2 = np.in1d(ID2, ID1)`, however `ID1[mask1]` has different size from `ID2[mask2]`. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @HuanianZhang If ID1 and ID2 are ID arrays, that shouldn't happen. Are you sure they are 1D arrays?

Comment: Thank you. I assume the `ID1` and `ID2` are not unique. There are some repeated elements, which should explain why `ID1[mask1]` has different size from `ID2[mask2]`, They are 1D arrays, but the elements are 18 digits long interger.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your second table, table B, is sorted, you can do a sorted lookup, then check if the indexed element is actually found:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(B[:-1, 0], A[:, 0])
found = A[:, 0] == B[idx, 0]
np.hstack((A[found, :], B[idx[found], 1:]))
```

Result:

```
array([[ 101. ,    1. ,    1.2,    1.5,    1.8,    4.5,   10.5],
       [ 104. ,    1.5,    1.8,    2.2,    3.1,   10.8,    5.6]])
```

The last element of the B indices is excluded to simplify the case where the item in A is beyond the final element in B.  Without it, it is possible that the returned index would be greater than the length of B and cause indexing errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually the `ID`'s is not sorted. And they are 18 digits long interger.

Comment: 18 digits long integer fits in 64 bits but not in 53 bits, so the key column needs to be in integers, not floating point double.  The Pandas data structures make it much easier to work with mixed type arrays, or you can keep your key columns separate from the rest of your data.

Comment: To keep the code simple, sort the ID2 table beforehand.  Both searchsorted and in1d require sorted tables, though in1d does the sorting internally.  If you are going to do the join operation more than once it will save time to maintain sorted tables.

Comment: Thank you. Would you provide me some guide on Pandas dataframe merge to finish this. I assume the `ID1` and `ID2` are not unique. There are some repeated elements.

Comment: Okay, added as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

id1 = pd.read_csv('id1.txt')
id2 = pd.read_csv('id2.txt')
df = id1.merge(id2.sort_values(by='ID2').drop_duplicates('ID2').rename(columns={'ID2':'ID1'}))
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
   ID1    z    e   PA    n    RA   DEC
0  101  1.0  1.2  1.5  1.8   4.5  10.5
1  104  1.5  1.8  2.2  3.1  10.8   5.6
```

With large datasets you may need to do things in place:

```
# [Optional] sort locations and drop duplicates
id2.sort_values(by='ID2', inplace=True)
id2.drop_duplicates('ID2', inplace=True)

# columns that you are merging must have the same name
id2.rename(columns={'ID2':'ID1'}, inplace=True)

# perform the merge
df = id1.merge(id2)
```

---

Without drop_duplicates you get one row for each item:

```
df = id1.merge(id2.rename(columns={'ID2':'ID1'}))
print(id2)
print(df)
```

Giving:

```
   ID2    RA   DEC
0  101   4.5  10.5
1  107  90.1  55.5
2  102  30.5   3.3
3  103  60.1  40.6
4  104  10.8   5.6
5  103  60.1  40.6
6  104  10.9   5.6
   ID1    z    e   PA    n    RA   DEC
0  101  1.0  1.2  1.5  1.8   4.5  10.5
1  104  1.5  1.8  2.2  3.1  10.8   5.6
2  104  1.5  1.8  2.2  3.1  10.9   5.6
```

---

Note that this solution preserves the different types for the columns:

```
>>> id1.ID1.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> id1[' z'].dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Since you have spaces after the comma in the header row those spaces became part of the column name, hence need to refer to the second column using id1[' z'].  By modifying the read statement, this is no longer necessary:

```
>>> id1 = pd.read_csv('id1.txt', skipinitialspace=True)
>>> id1.z.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: If you put it in an array (which you need to do for `np.unique`), then all columns must have the same format, which only gives you 16 digits for your ids, not the 20 digits you get using 64-bit integers.  You indicated that ids may be 18 digits, so double precision isn't enough.